# OpenGL doesnt run on emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, opengl, emulation

I have been trying to run the two OpenGL sample codes that developer.android.com offers without any luck so far.they compile and deploy OK but fail to run on emulator no matter what configuration it has nevertheless they work fine on the device. so it have to be the emulator not the code. I have been reading these threads about this very problem (it seems that it is a common issue) but nothing works for me . first of all my working environment is :

- windows 7 - 32 bit
- ADT bundle for windows x86 v22.2.1
- JDK 7
- ATI Radeon X1600 series with updated driver

I suspect that app's failure has something to do with this error im getting when the emulator runs :

```
    Failed to create Context 0x3005
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
```

i have checked and unchecked "Use Host GPU" and "Snapshot" options but nothing changed. I changed the ram and internal storage but nothing happened neither . I even changed the `android:installLocation` which seems to be the problem for some , no luck again .

my guess is either a bunch of library files are missing from ADT bundle or i have to install some packages from SDK manager .

i have :

- libEGL_translator.dll
- libGLES_CM_translator.dll
- libGLES_V2_translator.dll
- libOpenglRender.dll

and

- lib64EGL_translator.so
- lib64GLES_CM_translator.so
- lib64GLES_V2_translator.so
- lib64OpenglRender.so

in my `sdk/tools/lib`

and as for the packages, i have :

1. Android 4.3 (API 18)

   - SDK Platform
   - Android SDK Build-tools
2. Android Support libraries

installed.

Any helps or workarounds people? this is killing me ...

Answer (score 3):

The emulator bundled with ADT is pretty much broken. I could never get it to work with opengl enabled.

The emulator shipped with Android Studio is much improved and can handle most of my development usage.

Occasionally some apps still crash in the built in emulator. Then I use an alternative emulator like genymotion or leapdroid. They are all compatible with adb so Android Studio will just connect to them. Leapdroid works for me best in term of app compatibility. http://www.leapdroid.com/

You can find more information at 
[How to use a different emulator in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796452/how-to-use-a-different-emulator-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

The errors you report indicate an incomplete, damaged or faulty driver installation. In short the errors tell, that the emulator is not able to load specific OpenGL functionality, namely functions available only with a proper driver installation. I suggest you try cleansing your system of any graphics drivers, except the standard VGA/VESA driver and do a fresh install with drivers downloaded from the AMD website.