# How to use a different emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

I have issues with the build in qemu emulator in Android Studio. There are some other Android emulators out there. How to configure Android Studio to use a different emulator? I use leapdroid emulator http://www.leapdroid.com to run apps and games.

Comment: Can't you just create a new Device Emulator? There should be images that were downloaded with your SDK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Leapdroid is compatible with Android adb, i.e., using the same port numbers starting with 5555, so there is really nothing special to do, pretty much same as what you do with the built-in Android emulator. If you run "adb devices", you will see a device named as "emulator-5554".

Here are the steps:

1. Launch Leapdroid vm, which contains android 4.4.4 image
2. Launch Android Studio, and click Android emulator tab, a device named as "Emulator unknown 4.4.4" will show up inside the device list, and you can select it.
3. You should be able to see the logcat, and debug your Android app, etc.

Make sure that you close all other emulators first, in case there are conflicts.

I've also attached two screenshots for clarifications:

[image: Android Studio connecting to Leapdroid VM]
[image: Leapdroid vm running]

Answer (score 1):

There are options like:

**Genymotion**: https://www.genymotion.com/

config with Androi Studio [here](http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2013/11/22/android-studio-plus-genymotion-emulator/)

**Visual Studio Emulator for Android** 
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx

config with Android Studio [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/07/20/using-the-visual-studio-emulator-for-android-from-android-studio-or-eclipse-with-adt/)

I hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)? It is the fastest emulator I've come across.
-Download it from their website for your required system specifications.
-You will also need an account to download the device images.
-Once all that is done, when you simply run the emulator, the device should show up in your ADB choose device window.
-You may also want to use [Genymotion plugin for android studio](https://www.genymotion.com/plugins/) for easy launch of virtual devices.

Comment: Now Genymotion is paid only :(

Comment: Damn that sucks